# TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable in python, while saving the workbook

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to create a script where I first read a macro file, save it as a xlsx file and perform some tasks on it. Creating a subset dataframe from this excel file. After refreshing this excel again a subset dataframe is extracted and then these two distinct files with dataframes are compared.
The script runs fine for the first time, but next time it shows the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1234\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\sell_triggers1.py", line 47, in <module>
    wb.Save()
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

If I close all the excel instances from the windows task manager, then script will work fine.

Please help where I am going wrong. I am very new to Python and can't figure out the issue. Thanks

```
import win32com.client
import pandas as pd
import os
import smtplib
import numpy as np
import time

excel = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')

# Load the .XLSM file into Excel
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(r'D:\\MY DOCUMENTS\\WATCHLIST.xlsm')

# Save it in .XLSX format to a different filename
excel.DisplayAlerts = False
wb.DoNotPromptForConvert = True
wb.CheckCompatibility = False
wb.SaveAs(r"WATCHLIST1.xlsx", FileFormat=51, ConflictResolution=2)
wb.Close(True)
excel.Application.Quit()


# Load the .XLSX file into Pandas
df = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\1234\\Documents\\WATCHLIST1.xlsx", sheet_name='TRADES')

df1 = df[["Ticker1","Current_price","Condition(Current_price>STOP SMAW10)"]].copy()

df2 = df1[(df1["Condition(Current_price>STOP SMAW10)"] == 2)]

df2.to_excel("watchlist2.xlsx", index= False)


# refreshing the workbook and saving it

xlapp = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(r'C:\\Users\\1234\\Documents\\WATCHLIST1.xlsx')
wb.RefreshAll()
xlapp.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()
xlapp.DisplayAlerts = False
time.sleep(20)
wb.Save()
wb.Close(True)
xlapp.Application.Quit()

 
# again reading the watchlist and storing the filtered output to an excel file after refresh
df = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\1234\\Documents\\WATCHLIST1.xlsx", sheet_name='TRADES')

df1 = df[["Ticker1","Current_price","Condition(Current_price>STOP SMAW10)"]].copy()

df2 = df1[(df1["Condition(Current_price>STOP SMAW10)"] == 2)]

df2.to_excel("watchlist3.xlsx", index= False)

# reading two different output files

df1 = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\1234\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\Scripts\\watchlist2.xlsx")
df2 = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\1234\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\Scripts\\watchlist3.xlsx")

# preparing a comparison output

df1 = df1.set_index('Ticker1')
df2 = df2.set_index('Ticker1')

df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2],sort=False)
df3a = df3.stack().groupby(level=[0,1]).unique().unstack(1).copy()

df3a.loc[~df3a.index.isin(df2.index),'status'] = 'deleted' # if not in df2 index then deleted
df3a.loc[~df3a.index.isin(df1.index),'status'] = 'new'     # if not in df1 index then new
idx = df3.stack().groupby(level=[0,1]).nunique() # get modified cells. 
df3a.loc[idx.mask(idx <= 1).dropna().index.get_level_values(0),'status'] = 'modified'
df3a['status'] = df3a['status'].fillna('same') # assume that anything not fufilled by above rules is the same.

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('./watchlist4.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Write each dataframe to a different worksheet.
df3a.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Data')

# set column width for 'Data'. 
worksheet = writer.sheets['Data']
worksheet.set_column(0, 2, 15)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Comment: `wb.Close(True)` should save the workbook, so I'd just remove `wb.Save()`.

Comment: Many thanks for the comment, I tried the same, now the error is wb.Close(True)
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable.

Comment: What's the difference beween `xlapp.Workbooks.Open` and `excel.Workbooks.Open`? Why do you need two of these win32 objects?

Comment: Thanks. Please ignore my inexperience, I thought every time, I need to dispatch excel application if I need to save and work on excel file. I removed the second win32 line, but still the script runs the first time. Post that it is the same issue, but at a different line: wb.SaveAs(r"WATCHLIST1.xlsx", FileFormat=51, ConflictResolution=2)
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
Here is a workaround.
I noticed that the save() is successfully done anyway.
So, I catch errors via try/except to ignore it and continue processing.
I noticed also that if the program does not go further to the close() and quit(),
the file is kept 'in use' somewhere : I get a 'permission denied' error on open() when I try to run the program again.
Needed to open the file with Excel and save it to be able to rerun the python program without open() error.

I guess that the program should go further anyway trying to terminate all related Excel objects.

Here is the final code

```
import win32com.client as win32
print(f"Formatting EXCEL file {outFileName}")  
xlApp = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(outFileName)
ws = wb.Worksheets['SheetName']
ws.Columns.AutoFit()
try :
    wb.save()
except Exception as e :  # can do better code by selecting the specific error
    pass
try :
    wb.close()
except Exception as e :  # can do better code by selecting the specific error
    pass
xlApp.Application.Quit() # this one don't raise error
```